# How to check if the header file is located in the main.c using ifeq in Makefile(vim)

Tags: c, makefile

I want to check if the header file exist in my "c code" using "ifeq" in the Makefile. I'm using "test -f" to check if the string exist in the c file. I have tested it by commenting out the header file in my c code, however it never enters the "ifeq" statement when I re-initialise the header file. What am I missing in my "ifeq" statement? I'm using a vim text file on Linux. Thanks

I have looked into the shell command of "test -f" but couldn't figure out what i'm doing wrong

```
ifeq ($(test -f my.h && echo true) , true)
     CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_H
 else
     $(info VAR="$(VAR)")
 endif
```

It enters into the else statement when the header file is initialised

Comment: The command you are invoking belongs to the shell environment, not Make's. You should therefore use [make's `shell`command](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)

Comment: Furthermore, you seem to be trying to resolve a simple problem in a very convoluted way... Can't you just `#define CONFIG_H` directly in your header? It's only a suggestion, your solution is certainly adequate but for the example you posted it could be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is this:

```
ifeq ($(wildcard my.h),)
    $(info VAR="$(VAR)")
else
    CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_H
endif
```